# What is the difference between the trigonometric ratios and triangle ratios?

Tags: trigonometry

Recently on a homework assignment for a teacher, I got a question wrong and was just wondering why. My teacher told me that I was wrong but she couldn't give me a reason why. Here is the problem:

Find $\csc{\theta}$ and $\cos{\theta}$ if $\tan{\theta} = \frac{3}{4}$ and $\sec{\theta} < 0$

My attempt was since tangent is just sin/cos, that the cosecant would just be $\frac{1}{3}$, and consequently the cos would just be 4.

However my teacher said that I was supposed to draw a right triangle and solve it that way. I understand where she is coming from, but what I don't understand is how that disproves my answer.

Comment: And what was **your** attempt?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot that.

Comment: Notational tip: you can enclose entire expressions in dollar signs. Also, many common functions, including most trigonometric ones have their own commands that makes them look good.

Comment: Well, I can see what the answer is, but I still can't work out what your error was.

Comment: $\cos$ can't be $4$, it should be between $-1$ and $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your answer can't possibly be correct, because the cosine of an angle is ALWAYS between -1 and 1. So there is no angle at all whose cosine is 4. Sine is also between -1 and 1, so for any angle $\theta$, $\csc\theta \leq-1$ or $\geq 1$.

I can see why you might think that $\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac{3}{4}$ would imply $\sin \theta = 3$ and $\cos \theta = 4$, but fractions are a bit trickier than that. If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{3}{4}$, there are lots of possible values for $a$ and $b$. For example, you could have $a = 3$ and $b = 4$, or you could have $a = 6$ and $b = 8$, or you could have $a = -3/5$ and $b = -4/5$. For all of these, the quotient simplifies to 3/4.

What this tells us is that just knowing the result of dividing two numbers doesn't imply we can find each of the original two numbers. Fortunately, the trig functions are related in more ways than just $\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$. In particular, you have the pythagorean identity $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$, which is what your teacher was suggesting you use.

Comment: Alright, I guess this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The value of cosine is always between -1 and 1.

sec is less than 0 and cos is just the reciprocal of secant. Therefore, it has to be less than 0 as well.

Since tan is positive, and cosine is negative. The sine would be negative as well. Therefore, cosec, reciprocal of sine, is also negative.

Now you see why your teacher would want you to draw a triangle?

It is never a good idea to skip steps especially when you are just starting to learn. Also, it is critical that you stop using the method you are following. Because if the question was asking you for sine. You would probably answer it 3. Which is wrong because sine is also always between -1 and 1.

Comment: All the work we had been doing in that chapter had involved using trigonometric ratios to solve problems. I wasn't trying to take shortcuts, I was trying to use what we had learned. Also, we were never taught that sin and cos is between -1 and 1

Comment: We all learn something new every day. Now that you know that sine and cosine are always between -1 and 1. You can use that knowledge to check your answers. A lot of mathematical theories use that as one of the base points for proofs.

Comment: I am not sure how your course is structured. The easiest way to solve questions like these that involve ratios of 3,4,5 would be to make a right angle triangle with those particular numbers and 5 is always the hypotenuse of that triangle. But the base could be either 3 or 4. After that, you need to apply CAST rule to figure out the positive and negative values. 
Ignore this if you haven't learned CAST rule yet. Just practice with more examples and it will all come naturally to you.